# Boost Multiindex: Example compiles in cpp files but not in header

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index

I am trying to compile the boost Multiindex [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#key_extraction)

I have a project consisting of multiple header and source files. 
When I put the following code into some source file it works well, but it would give me the errors below, when I this code into a header file. Both header and cpp include the required boost header files and boost works fine otherwise.

I have never encountered such a problem and I am quite confused as what the reason could be.

```
// define a multiply indexed set with indices by id and name
typedef multi_index_container<
  employee,
  indexed_by<
    // sort by employee::operator<
    ordered_unique<identity<employee> >,

    // sort by less<string> on name
    ordered_non_unique<member<employee,std::string,&employee::name> >
  > 
> employee_set;
```

where employee is a simple struct.

```
void print_out_by_name(const employee_set& es)
    {
      // get a view to index #1 (name)
     const employee_set::nth_index<1>::type& name_index=es.get<1>();
      // use name_index as a regular std::set
    }
```

missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'employee_set::nth_index'
         const employee_set::nth_index<1>::type& name_index=es.get<1>();

expected unqualified-id
         const employee_set::nth_index<1>::type& name_index=es.get<1>();

Answer (score 1):

try

```
const typename employee_set::nth_index<1>::type& name_index=es.get<1>();
```

nth_index<1>::type is something called a depended type. But the compiler doesn't know whether it is a type of value or whatever. And writing typename tells him that it is indeed a type.

Comment: Thats what I thought too at first, but when I do this I get the error:  error: 
      use 'template' keyword to treat 'nth_index' as a dependent template name
         const typename employee_set::nth_index<1>::type& name_index=es.get<1>();

Also isn't it weird that it worked in the cpp file but not in the h file?

Comment: very strange indent, I never got that error msg. Can you use c++11? if so. const auto& is your friend

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately, I can't use c++11

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the C++ compiler, it is immaterial whether the code is located in a `.hpp` or in a `.cpp` file: header files are (usually) not compiled on their own, but rather processed as part of the `.cpp` files they're `#include`d into.

So, your problem must be related to some change you are inadvertently applying when moving code between "header" and "source" files. As it looks,

```
void print_out_by_name(const employee_set& es);
```

is not a template function or part of class template and hence it can't deal with dependent types or anything that might require the insertion of `typename`s. Maybe this is part of a larger class where `employee_set` is actually a template parameter?

Comment: I typedefed employee_set in A.h and print_out_by_name is a function of class A.

Comment: Do you mean `print_out_by_name` is a member function of class `A`? Is class `A` a class template? If so, try

    const typename employee_set::template nth_index<1>::type& name_index=es.template get<1>();

Comment: Nice, the es.template get<1>() worked; why is that?  Btw: Yes, I meant that print_out_by_name is a member funciton of A.

Comment: Check for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords . Note that your original problem does not depend on whether the offending code lives in a header or a .cpp file.